# Using Regex to find "<img .../>" and "<script ...> </script>" in HTML string

Tags: html, regex, scala

I am trying to use Regular Expressions for the first time to search for images and scripts in webpages in Scala. The expressions I've come up with are

Images:

```
/(<img\S+\s+\/>)+/
```

Scripts:

```
/(<script\s+\S+><\/script>)+/
```

I don't really know anything about HTML code or using Regex so I'm not sure what I need in order to specify that it should match `<img .../>` where the `...` could be any amount of characters or whitespace. This is just a small part of a programming assignment I'm writing in Scala and we have to use Regex.

Comment: What is the question? Have you found situations where these regexes don't work? (I can think of a few.)

Comment: Also, required reading: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/1016716

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A regex like `<img[^>]*>` would match `<img..........>`.

A regex like `<script.*?</script>` would match a single `<script...>...</script>` instance.  The `?` is necessary to prevent it from matching everything from the first `<script...>` tag to the last `</script>` tag.

(Feel free to add back in the capturing `( )`'s, the `\` escapes, and surround with the regex delimiting `/ /` tokens.  I removed them to focus on the regular expressions themselves, without the [leaning toothpick syndrome](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leaning_toothpick_syndrome) and other noise.)

While these are better than the ones you proposed, they will still break in many circumstances.  RegEx is ***not*** designed to parse HTML.

```
<script>
  <!-- This "</script>" doesn't end the script, but fools the RegEx -->
</script>
```